# Alternatives to the Fourier transform

Tags: functions, approximation

I am searching for methods which can be used to represent bounded real-valued functions defined on a finite interval. More specifically, I am interested in approximations of such functions which have a finite number of controllable parameters or equivalently, approximations of such functions which can be represented in a finite-dimensional function space. Furthermore, it would be very desirable if an order could be associated with the basis functions of such a function space with respect to some metric.

Comment: It sounds like you want a unitary integral transform, which has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419433/fourier-transform-is-unitary-proof-and-other-unitary-integral-operators). The only alternative to Fourier that comes to mind is [Hartley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_transform).

Comment: You might be interested by Wavelets?