# Showing that Fourier transform on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a unitary operator

Tags: functional-analysis

**Definition**: An operator $U\colon H\to H$ is called *unitary* if $\langle Ux,Uy \rangle=\langle x,y \rangle$ for all $x,y\in H$ and $\text{Im}U=H$.

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely unitary operators. In the text, the author gives the following statement without any proof:

> The Fourier transform on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$
> $$
> (Ff)(\tau):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^{N} f(t)e^{it\tau}dt\tag{1}
> $$
> is a unitary operator. The limit is understood in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ sense. Moreover, since $F^*=F^{-1}$, the formula for $F^{-1}$ is obtained by changing $i$ to $-i$ in $(1)$.

I know that if $F$ is unitary then $F^{-1}=F^*$. Also, I know that
$$
(F^*f)(\tau):=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^{N} f(t)\overline{e^{it\tau}}dt=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^{N} f(t)e^{-it\tau}dt,\tag{2}
$$
hence I understand since $F^*=F^{-1}$, the formula for $F^{-1}$ is obtained by changing $i$ to $-i$ in $(1)$. What's not obvious to me is that $\langle Ff,Fg \rangle=\langle f,g \rangle$. My attempt at this is:
$$
\langle Ff,Fg \rangle=\int_\mathbb{R}(Ff)(\tau)\overline{(Fg)(\tau)}d\tau,
$$
and then I've tried expanding this out, etc., but always seem to get nowhere.

Comment: You can look at Rudin's RCA for this basic result and seek help if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Actually, I don't see where this exact result can be found in that text. Can you reference me to where it is located?

Comment: Look at the section "The Plancherel Theorem".

Comment: This is also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1419433/121671)

Comment: Your question will likely be "closed" here, for better or for worse, since it asks about a thing that meets a (in contemporary math) low threshhold of well-known-ness, namely, Plancherel for Fourier Transform...